# what is the easiest Oralce SQL certification

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle SQL, I started self teaching myself using Youtube and I am liking it. so now I would like to study for the easiest Oracle SQL certification and go from there, can someone please tell me what are the certificates that I can study and test for in the future staring from the easiest to the hardest. I am also open if you can recommend a better way to study oracle SQL for beginners

Comment: Visit Oracle's Certification pages, here: https://education.oracle.com/oracle-certification-paths-all. I guess it isn't about "which is the easiest", but "what do you plan to do / be in the future".

Comment: my goal for the near future is to be an Oracle DBA, I have few years if experience supporting oracle but now I want to study Oracle SQL to take things to the next lever. Im asking for the easiest because I don't have any programming background, once I get my foot on the door then the sky is the limit. I also would like to draw a carrier path for me as Oracle DBA by finding out the easiest to the hardest certification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to SQL, my suggestion would be to target below certifications:

**#1: Oracle Database SQL Certified Associate** 
https://education.oracle.com/oracle-database-sql-certified-associate/trackp_457

**#2: Oracle Database PL/SQL Developer Certified Professional** 
https://education.oracle.com/oracle-database-pl-sql-developer-certified-professional/trackp_148